# Add javascript to separate file .js

Tags: javascript, html

I added a javascript to html file to match password,

````
<script>function checkPassword(form) {```**code**```}</script>
<html><form onSubmit = "return checkPassword(this)"><html>
````

it works fine. But i want to separate the javascript to a .js file. Is there any way to do it??

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: `<script src="javascript.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a src attribute to your script tag and pointing it towards your js file.

```
<script src="./yourJsFile.js"></script>
<html><form onSubmit = "return checkPassword(this)"><html>
```